# win.toggleTabBar() not working in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

The [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wintoggletabbar-macos) gives an option to show the tab bar (`win.toggleTabBar()`). But for the life of me, I'm just not able to make it work.

The doc says *"Toggles the visibility of the tab bar **if native tabs are enabled**"*. What are native tabs? How do I enable them.

I want to be able to show the tab bar in electron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window):

> **tabbingIdentifier** *String (optional)* - Tab group name, allows opening the window as a native tab on macOS 10.12+. Windows with the same tabbing identifier will be grouped together. This also adds a native new tab button to your window's tab bar and allows your app and window to receive the new-window-for-tab event.

This was [added in 2017](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/9052) to allow for "native tabs" in OSX. In order for it to work, you must pass a `tabbingIdentifier` when creating a new BrowserWindow.

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const win = new BrowserWindow({ 
   tabbingIdentifier: 'myTabs'
});
```

Comment: Indeed. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Btw, doesn't electron have chrome tabs? How are native tabs different?